# How To Paginated Datatable With Mysql Database In Flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter, datatable

I am trying to make paginated data table with MYSQL database in flutter but I can not get any data in the table as below Images.

My Screenshot

[image]

MySQL

[image]

PHP Code:

```
<?php $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx'); if(!$db){ echo "Database connection fail"; } $querysql = "SELECT * FROM employees"; $result = $db->query($querysql); $list = array(); if($result->num_rows >0) { while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { array_push($list,$row); } $db->close(); echo json_encode($list); } ?>
```

Flutter Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Users {
  String id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  Users({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName});
  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Users(
      id: json['id'] as String,
      firstName: json['first_name'] as String,
      lastName: json['last_name'] as String,
    );
  }
}
class getDataSources extends DataTableSource {
  getDataSources(this.data);
  final List<Users> data;
  int _selectedCount = 0;
  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(
        index: index,
        cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Text('${data[index].id}')),
          DataCell(Text('${data[index].firstName}')),
          DataCell(Text('${data[index].lastName}')),
        ]
    );
  }
  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;
  @override
  int get rowCount => data.length;
  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;
}
```

Comment: If you are using [sqflie](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) it supports `limit` and `page` parameters for retrieving data by pages.

Comment: Actually I want to retrieve all the records from my database but I just want It to show on the screen something like 10 rows per page.

Comment: How do you connected to your database?

Comment: here is my php database connection and retrive: <?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx');

if(!$db){
  echo "Database connection fail";
}

$querysql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
$result = $db->query($querysql);
$list = array();
if($result->num_rows >0) {
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($list,$row);
   }
   $db->close();
   echo json_encode($list);
}

?>

Comment: I want to share the source code too but it shows this message(It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.) so I can't post it

Comment: How do you connect to the database?

Comment: Here is the code in flutter connect to database: getAllUserList() async {
    var response = await http.get("https://kctn2013.orgfree.com/test01/viewtesting.php");
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _data = json.decode(response.body);
      });
      return _data;
    }
  }

Comment: You should filter your data on MySQL side but pages and limit must be stored and managed on Flutter side. Try to add limit and page to your db request.

Comment: here is the error message: E/flutter ( 6093): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Users>'
E/flutter ( 6093): #0      _DatabaseTablePagingState.getAllUserList.<anonymous closure> (package:loningv03/databasepiginated.dart:76:9)
E/flutter ( 6093): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1269:30)
E/flutter ( 6093): #2      _DatabaseTablePagingState.getAllUserList (package:loningv03/databasepiginated.dart:75:7)
E/flutter ( 6093): <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: You should to handle raw data from database and cast it to a data that need on Flutter side.

Comment: Actually I want to get output result on the screen but I get nothing yet. I couldn't find out the problem. Could you help to fix?

Comment: Can you show output from database response?